# How do I combine routing and uri segments to put the user id in the url when on a specific user page?

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I am trying to attach the user id to the url when viewing their page or the same thing when viewing another users page. I am getting this error `Unable to load the requested file: account/profile/218.php` With this code:

//Routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['profile/:num'] = "account/profile"; 
//I've also tried doing 
$route['profile/([a-z]+)/(\d+)'] = "profile/$1/id_$2";
```

//Controller without the uri segment which produces the above stated error:

```
public function profile() 
    {

        $this->load->helper('date');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $session_id = $this->session->userdata['id'];
        $this->load->model('account_model');
            $user = $this->account_model->user();
        $data['user'] = $user;
        $data['profile_icon'] = 'profile';
        $data['main_content'] = 'account/profile/'.$user['id'];
        $this->load->view('includes/templates/profile_template', $data);

    }
```

and when I use this:

```
public function profile() 
{

    $this->load->helper('date');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $session_id = $this->session->userdata['id'];
    $this->load->model('account_model');
        $user = $this->account_model->user();
    $data['user'] = $user;
    $user['id'] = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $data['profile_icon'] = 'profile';
    $data['main_content'] = 'account/profile/'.$user['id'];
    $this->load->view('includes/templates/profile_template', $data);

}
```

it produces this error:

> Unable to load the requested file: account/profile/.php

****EDIT

HTACCESS

```
Deny from all
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$route['profile/:num'] = "account/profile/$1";
```

and remove index.php in your config file

Comment: What should I replace $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; with? If I take it out it won't load any of my pages.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

"Removing the index.php file"

Comment: I was able to get rid of index.php which is great however, I'm still getting the same Unable to load the requested file: account/profile/218.php error when I get rid of $user['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3); however when I add $user['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3); I get Unable to load the requested file: account/profile/.php error. Also, please note that after the htaccess changes when it poses that error it's loading my header nav structure without any css

Comment: upon further investigation getting rid of the index.php is killing my css links. I'm using base_url() for their paths which does not include index.php

Answer (score 1):

in the **application/config/routes.php** file add the

`$route['profile/(:num)'] = "account/profile/$1";`

More about routing you can read [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

```
public function profile( $user_id ) 
{

    $this->load->helper('date');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $session_id = $this->session->userdata['id'];
    $this->load->model('account_model');
    $user = $this->account_model->user();
    $data['user'] = $user;
    $user['id'] = $user_id;
    $data['profile_icon'] = 'profile';
    $data['main_content'] = 'account/profile/'.$user['id'];
    $this->load->view('includes/templates/profile_template', $data);

}
```

Add to the profile method the extra param - witch will be the user ID
so the `$user['id'] = $user_id;` no need to use the `$this->uri->segment(4);` method.

I recommend you modify the htaccess file like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: $config['url_suffix'] = '';

Comment: and I think this is what you meant? $data['user'] = $user;
  $user['id'] = $user_id;
  $data['profile_icon'] = 'profile';
  $data['main_content'] = 'account/profile/'.$user_id;
  $this->load->view('includes/templates/profile_template', $data); attaching "$user_id" to the url and not $user['id'] as in your above example. With both versions I'm still getting a page load error

Comment: with your exact code it's not loading the page still AND getting this error Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Account::profile()

Filename: controllers/account.php

Line Number: 140